# C++ List showing last 3 items from table

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object, constructor

Hey i have a table of teams with the names and the points they have and i'm trying to figure out how to display the last 3 teams with the least amount of points in the table?

It displays all the teams and i want it to display only the last 3 in the table but don't know what way to go about it.

These are my Accessors

string  GetName
int   GetPoints

int lowest = 1000;

```
for (int i = 0; i < numTeams; i++)
{
    if (league[i].GetPoints() < lowest)
    {
        lowest = league[i].GetPoints();
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < numTeams; i++)
{
    if (league[i].GetPoints() == lowest)
    {
        cout << "\tThe lowest goals against is: " << league[i].GetName() << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What about sorting the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you don't need variable `lowest`, if you would sort the data before printing.

```
#include <algorithm>

// Sort using a Lambda expression.
std::sort(std::begin(league), std::end(league), [](const League &a, const League &b) {
    return a.GetPoints() < b.GetPoints();   
});

int last = 3;

for (int i = 0; i < last; i++)
{
    cout << "\tThe lowest goals against is: " << league[i].GetName() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

U could probably start by sorting your array

```
#include <algorithm>

std::array<int> foo;
std::sort(foo.begin(), foo.end());
```

and then Iterate From Your Last Element to your Last - 3. (U can use Reverse Iterators)

```
for (std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator it = v.rend() ; it != v.rend() + 3; 
it++) {
    //Do something
}
```

or by using auto

```
for (auto it = v.rend() ; it != v.rend() + 3; ++it) {
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In my example I've created test class(TestTeam) to implement several important methods for objects in your task. 
I use `std::sort` method to sort container of objects, by default std::sort compares objects by `less`(<) operation, so I have overrided operator `<` for TestTeam object

```
bool operator < ( const TestTeam& r) const
{
    return GetPoints() < r.GetPoints();
}
```

Also we could pass as third parameter another compare method or lambda method as shown in below answers:

```
std::sort(VecTeam.begin(), VecTeam.end(), [](const TestTeam& l, const TestTeam& r)
                  {
                      return l.GetPoints() < r.GetPoints();
                  });
```

And example when we use global method to compare:

```
bool CompareTestTeamLess(const TestTeam& l, const TestTeam& r)
{
    return l.GetPoints() < r.GetPoints();
}           

//...
// some code
//...     

// In main() we use global method to sort
std::sort(VecTeam.begin(), VecTeam.end(), ::CompareTestTeamLess);
```

You can try my code with vector as container:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

// Test class for example
class TestTeam
{
public:
    TestTeam(int16_t p, const std::string& name = "Empty name"):mPoints(p), mName(name)
    {
    };

    int16_t GetPoints() const {return mPoints;}
    const std::string& GetName() const {return mName;}

    void SetName( const std::string& name ) {mName=name;}

    bool operator < ( const TestTeam& r) const
    {
        return GetPoints() < r.GetPoints();
    }

private:
    int16_t mPoints;
    std::string mName;

};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    const uint32_t COUNT_LOWEST_ELEMENTS_TO_FIND = 3;

    // Fill container by test data with a help of non-explicit constructor to solve your task
    std::vector<TestTeam> VecTeam {3,5,8,9,11,2,14,7};

    // Here you can do others manipulations with team data ...

    //Sort vector by GetPoints overloaded in less operator. After sort first three elements will be with lowest points in container
    std::sort(VecTeam.begin(), VecTeam.end());

    //Print results as points - name
    std::for_each( VecTeam.begin(), VecTeam.begin() + COUNT_LOWEST_ELEMENTS_TO_FIND, [] (TestTeam el)
                      {
                          std::cout << el.GetPoints() << " - " << el.GetName() << std::endl;
                      } );
}
```

I made test class TestTeam only to implement test logic for your object.
If you try launch the program you can get next results:

```
2 - Empty name
3 - Empty name
5 - Empty name
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: Seems like overengineering, especially where is vector filling defined.

Comment: Ugnius, thanks for comment. I've edited my answer ant improved some explanations

Comment: Alex, now it's better. But still, the answer itself is very long: a lot of explanations for the simple problem. For instance, you could avoid example of class creation because T.Ryan has already done that. Cheers!

Comment: Ugnius, thanks for your feedback. I used example of class to explain inline override less operator. Also I thought that topic starter would like to check my solution on his computer without any additional coding. Cheers!